# Duplicate Filename in GCP Storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I am streaming files to GCP Storage (bucket). Doing so results in a frequent error (roughly 2 million times a day) claiming that my filename policy must generate a unique name. I've tried multiple ways of guaranteeing a unique name such as using currentTimeMillis, currentThread, encrypting the file name, etc... They all appear to eliminate the error for a couple of hours/a day before it returns with the same frequency. I haven't encountered a situation where a file was missing, but I also haven't searched extensively. This is my writer:

```
pipeline.apply("Read PubSub Events", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription())) 
                    .apply(options.getWindowDuration() + " Window",
                                Window.<PubsubMessage>into(FixedWindows.of(parseDuration(options.getWindowDuration())))
                                    .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
                                    .discardingFiredPanes()
                                    .withAllowedLateness(parseDuration("24h")))
                    .apply(new GenericFunctions.extractMsg())
                    .apply(FileIO.<String, String>writeDynamic()
                            .by(new datePartition(options.getOutputFilenamePrefix()))
                            .via(TextIO.sink())
                            .withNumShards(options.getNumShards())
                            .to(options.getOutputDirectory())
                            .withNaming(type -> FileIO.Write.defaultNaming(type, ".txt"))
                            .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()));
```

I can elaborate on any non-google methods that we use if needed. This is the behomoth of an error StackDriver returns:

```
exception:  "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filename policy must generate unique filenames, but generated the same name gs://myBucket/myProject/2019/01/21/13h/myProject-2123065519-2019-01-21T12:58:00.000Z-2019-01-21T13:00:00.000Z-00000-of-00001.txt for file results FileResult{tempFilename=gs://myBucket/myProject/.temp-beam-2019-01-17_20-30-37-1/2e2c99ef-6508-4f10-ada4-e5c108b1d884, shard=0, window=[2019-01-21T12:58:00.000Z..2019-01-21T13:00:00.000Z), paneInfo=PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0, onTimeIndex=0}} and FileResult{tempFilename=gs://myBucket/myProject/.temp-beam-2019-01-17_20-30-37-1/2112c27f-8e0c-4831-b3fe-fbefe9ed560e, shard=0, window=[2019-01-21T12:58:00.000Z..2019-01-21T13:00:00.000Z), paneInfo=PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0, onTimeIndex=0}}
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:185)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.java:58)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.java:40)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:135)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:45)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:50)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:202)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:160)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1226)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:141)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:965)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filename policy must generate unique filenames, but generated the same name gs://myBucket/myProject/2019/01/21/13h/myProject-2123065519-2019-01-21T12:58:00.000Z-2019-01-21T13:00:00.000Z-00000-of-00001.txt for file results FileResult{tempFilename=gs://myBucket/myProject/.temp-beam-2019-01-17_20-30-37-1/2e2c99ef-6508-4f10-ada4-e5c108b1d884, shard=0, window=[2019-01-21T12:58:00.000Z..2019-01-21T13:00:00.000Z), paneInfo=PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0, onTimeIndex=0}} and FileResult{tempFilename=gs://myBucket/myProject/.temp-beam-2019-01-17_20-30-37-1/2112c27f-8e0c-4831-b3fe-fbefe9ed560e, shard=0, window=[2019-01-21T12:58:00.000Z..2019-01-21T13:00:00.000Z), paneInfo=PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0, onTimeIndex=0}}
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:34)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$FinalizeTempFileBundles$FinalizeFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:326)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:45)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:50)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:273)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:621)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:71)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:128)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:326)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:45)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:50)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:273)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:621)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:609)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReshuffleOverrideFactory$ReshuffleWithOnlyTrigger$1.processElement(ReshuffleOverrideFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReshuffleOverrideFactory$ReshuffleWithOnlyTrigger$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:326)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:45)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:50)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:183)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filename policy must generate unique filenames, but generated the same name gs://myBucket/myProject/2019/01/21/13h/myProject-2123065519-2019-01-21T12:58:00.000Z-2019-01-21T13:00:00.000Z-00000-of-00001.txt for file results FileResult{tempFilename=gs://myBucket/myProject/.temp-beam-2019-01-17_20-30-37-1/2e2c99ef-6508-4f10-ada4-e5c108b1d884, shard=0, window=[2019-01-21T12:58:00.000Z..2019-01-21T13:00:00.000Z), paneInfo=PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0, onTimeIndex=0}} and FileResult{tempFilename=gs://myBucket/myProject/.temp-beam-2019-01-17_20-30-37-1/2112c27f-8e0c-4831-b3fe-fbefe9ed560e, shard=0, window=[2019-01-21T12:58:00.000Z..2019-01-21T13:00:00.000Z), paneInfo=PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0, onTimeIndex=0}}
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_sdks_java_core.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:399)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$WriteOperation.finalizeDestination(FileBasedSink.java:656)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles.finalizeAllDestinations(WriteFiles.java:819)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles.access$1600(WriteFiles.java:112)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$FinalizeTempFileBundles$FinalizeFn.process(WriteFiles.java:796)
"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use methods that have been created for this.  For example, [UUID.randomUUID().toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString--) generates a type 4 UUID that can be used for naming files uniquely.

Comment: You can also prefix the file with something you recognize and append with stdunbar's recommendation. Something like `MyFolder/picture-${DATE}-${UUID}.jpg`

Comment: I'll give this a shot. That being said, why didn't my method work? I have a hard time imagining that encrypting a String containing a threadname and currentTimeMillis would generate the same String frequently.

Comment: So, I gave it a shot and there are no duplicate filename exceptions yet. Based on my previous attempts, they might still show up. That being said, there are now a bunch of out of memory/heap space and even garbage collection errors.

Comment: I tried again and looked more in depth. Strangely, using this method seems to have resolved the duplicate filename issue (at least temporarily), but now outputs a different file for every single log instead of aggregating a bunch of logs in a single file as specified by my window duration. Any ideas as to why that might happen?

Comment: Update: It appears like this resolved the error. I'm not sure if it was directly because of this, but I haven't received any duplicate filename errors since I pushed this change. I'll mark this answer as accepted. That being said, if anyone knows, could you explain what was causing the error to begin with?